# 2 reacts project deployed on same domain nginx issue with react router

Tags: reactjs, nginx, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

I have 2 different react projects that I want to serve on a single domain.

One is called 'client' which is for front office, one is admin which is for back office. The base URL is / for front office, and /admin for back office.

My nginx.conf looks like

```
`location /admin/ {
        alias /{{path_to_project}}/admin/build/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    location / {
        alias /{{path_to_project}}/client/build/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }`
```

It's working well for client. However for admin, it works if I type domain.com/admin in the URL, then let say I change the URL to domain.com/admin/something and refresh the page, Nginx load the client bundle even though it should load admin bundle as the request starts with /admin. Thanks for your help

Comment: What happens when you paste the url directly in a new tab instead of doing a refresh?

Comment: If I just paste domain.com/admin only, it's working good. But if I paste something like domain.com/admin/something-else it will load the client

Comment: can you do `curl -v http://example.com/admin/something-else` and see what is the output of the same?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm the output is the same, which is the client bundle

Comment: Please post the log, you can remove the actual content, interested in the headers and other details returned

Comment: *   Trying 127.0.0.1:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /admin/something-else HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> User-Agent: curl/7.65.2
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.17.10
< Date: Thu, 14 May 2020 05:35:48 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 2213
< Last-Modified: Wed, 13 May 2020 15:10:02 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< ETag: "5ebc0dca-8a5"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact

Answer (score 0):

you have to mention the home path in package.josn before you create to build you to set.

client-side package.json  home URL: domain.com

admin-side  package.jsno  home URL domain.com/admin

Error: there no error on Nginx config you have you use react history or hash router that keeps URL in react side

````
<HashRouter history={history}> 
   <Route path='/' component={IndexPage} exact={true} /> 
</HashRouter> ```
````

Comment: Still not working, I am 100% sure that the issue is on my Nginx config file which loads the incorrect bundle

Comment: can you please add more information with  network load and a screenshot of your Nginx config 

check the path in nginx alias /{{path_to_project}}/admin/build/;  
check this one for NGINX config
https://medium.com/the-software-reliever/static-react-app-in-20-mins-610662f47376